# How to remove cache option to label_attr with js on symfony3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

ATM, I manage to hide and show part of a form, but I can not display the label_attr of my elements, here is my code if you have an idea, thank you.

What I find strange is that I used the same method on another project and it worked well. In addition, ajax does not leave me any error, and it seems to me that everything is well connected.

My ajax :

```
(function ($) {    
function displayFTP(reponse){
    $('select#societe_form_HOST option').remove();
    $('select#societe_form_HOST').addClass('cache');
    $('label[for=societe_form_HOST').addClass('cache');

    if (reponse < 1){
        //afficher le menu déroulant
        $('select#societe_form_HOST').removeClass('cache');
        $('label[for=societe_form_HOST').removeClass('cache');
    }
    else {
        $('select#societe_form_HOST').addClass('cache');
        $('label[for=societe_form_HOST').addClass('cache');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#societe_form_serveurftp').on('change', function(e){
        if(this.checked){
            displayFTP(0);
        } else {
            displayFTP(1);
        }
    });
});
```

})(jQuery);

The fonction in my form :

```
            ->add('serveurftp',     CheckBoxType::class, array('attr'       => array('class' => "form-control"),
                                                            'label'         => 'Serveur FTP',
                                                            'label_attr'    => array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')))
            ->add('HOST',           TextType::class, array('attr'           => array('class' => "form-control cache"),
                                                            'label'         => 'Adresse du serveur :',
                                                            'label_attr'    => array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label cache')))
```

Comment: Your code is heavy for nothing. can't you manage to reduce it to a minimum example?

Comment: I have reduced to the minimum possible, I hope it will be easier.

Comment: Thanks :] Maybe it's just you miss closing your `]`?  `$('label[for=societe_form_HOST]')`

Comment: Nothing has changed :(